# Cropping TIFF images based on GeoJSON bounding boxes in Python

Tags: python, geojson, clip

I have a GeoJSON file that has bounding boxes (squares), and I also have many TIFF images. I want to crop the TIFF images exactly to bounding boxes provided by the GeoJSON file. While doing this, I want to preserve the coordinates of the TIFF images that is shown in QGIS. I searched a lot, but I could not find useful information about it.

Comment: Use gdalwarp with crop_to_cutline https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html.

Comment: Thank you very much! I do not know how to use gdalwarp and crop_to_cutline. Could you please provide me with a link to a similar problem?

Comment: Did you read the docs that @user30184 linked to? It has examples.

Comment: Yes, I saw them. However, they did not help much.

Answer (score 2):

As @user30184 has mentioned, `gdalwarp` can perform exactly what you are looking for and can be called from the command line with the appropriate operations flags.

If you are working from python (as has been tagged) and all your data is in the proper coordinate systems, you might find the `rasterio` and `fiona` command line tools a bit simpler to handle. The operation that you are looking for is called [`clip`](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cli.html#clip)

After installing both of those libraries, I would follow closely the example that the `rasterio` documentation shows. Something along the lines of...

```
rio clip input.tif output.tif --bounds $(fio info my_geojson.json --bounds)
```

...for each input.tif (using a loop or manually entering each if you aren't comfortable with shell scripting) would give you the desired outcome.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, this is what I get after running the code:               
ERROR 4: Unable to open EPSG support file gcs.csv.  Try setting the GDAL_DATA environment variable to point to the directory containing EPSG csv files.
ERROR:fiona._env:Unable to open EPSG support file gcs.csv.  Try setting the GDAL_DATA environment variable to point to the directory containing EPSG csv files.
Usage: rio clip [OPTIONS] INPUT OUTPUT

Error: Invalid value for "--bounds": '907499.9999450892' is not a valid bounding box representation

Comment: This looks like a GDAL issue. Is your GDAL_DATA environment variable set properly?

Comment: Hi Trevor, I do not really know.